# login system only accepts access to first item in the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

The problem with my simple login system is that it only accepts access from the first item in the database, which is "user1". When I tried to login the second user, which is "user2", it says incorrect though the username and password combination was actually correct. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sample', 'root', '');

    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            if($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location: success.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                die('Incorrect username and password combination');
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: success.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: you write select query with condition SELECT * FROM users where username="'.$_POST['username'].'". otherwise it fetch every thing from usertable.

Comment: you should consider using query with parameter for login system, not looping.

Comment: because your else condition is wrong.... in your code it always check only first one and its going in else condition when second user comes...and you used die so it will not loop any more and it will stop there only... that is the reason.... if you remove else condition then it will work... you have to handle by another condition if user is not available in database..

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: @tadman gonna keep that in mind

Comment: @premi i'll try that

Comment: @VijaysinhParmar so the `die()` ruins the code?

Comment: @JTrixx16 Yes....  if you remove die() it will work... but it will not handle if user is not in database

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Actually the problem is in your Logic and which is of using die() and exit() function. Look at your code the first iteration of while will not match with your user2 and the code will die(). The die() function ends all the flow of code hence every time you set username to user2 and run you will get the same result. Try to use die() or exit() function after the While Loop so the code moves to next iteration if not match on the first iteration.

**Explnation**
Moreover apply username and password by using where clause in query it will provide more benefits to you.

1. It will Minimize your code
2. By this logic which you are using at the moment, if your USER data increases
   it will increase your process time of LOGIN because it will first fetch all the rows from USER table then iterate over it un-till it finds the match against username.

But if you still want to continue with this approach you may use as following

**Code**

```
session_start();

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sample', 'root', '');

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    //if session is already set navigate to success.php 
    header('Location: success.php');
} else {
    //else if session is not set 
    //authenticate the user first
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            if ($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location: success.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
        return 'Incorrect username and password combination';
    } else {
        return 'username and password required';
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I remove the `exit()` and the `else` instead?

Comment: wait if you still want to use this code for login purpose, i am correcting this for you.

Comment: @JTrixx16 you may check my answer now

Comment: @JTrixx16 if you get help from this accept my answer.